# How to stop google blogger HTML editor from converting single quote into &#39;

Tags: html, google-blogger-api

Google blogger HTML editor automatically replaces single quote with `&#39;`. Is it possible to overcome this issue?

Comment: What do you mean it "affects functionality"? In the context of an HTML document, `'` and `&#39;` are functionally identical, surely?

Answer (score 1):

Try and use ` char instead of '